# How to predict next number from a given set of measurement data?

Tags: statistics

I have to do some experiment and measure it on a specific time 
0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36 months
$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{Month} &ID1 &    ID2 &    ID3 &    ID4 &    ID5 &    ID6\\\hline
0    & 101.7& 102.6& 101.7 &100.5 &100.4 &103.4\\
3     &103.4 &103.3 &101.4 &101.7& 100.5 &101.2\\
6     &100.7 &103.7 &101.6 &102    & 102.9& 102\\
9     &100.2 &100.6& 101.2& 97.9& 98.7 &99.5\\
12    & 99.8 &100.1& x  &     98.6& 100.4 &100.1\\
18     &98.7& x&  x & x      & x       &x\\
24     &101.3 &x  &x & x &      x&       x\\
36     &100.8 &x  &x&  x       &x  &     x\\
\end{array}
$$
Basically, all the numbers are from the measurement. So, could anyone please suggest how do I predict the numbers represented as "x" here ? Assume each ID are different type of items/products/equipment to be measured.

I would prefer to use the arithmetic mean and variance for the prediction. However, if anyone could suggest better idea, it would be nice.

Thank you in advance,
PTP

Comment: I made sure your table was readable (the text editor doesn't interpret newlines, spaces and tabulators as you might expect it to, so your numbers were a mess). Could you go through the table and make sure I didn't ruin anything?

Comment: Hello Arthur, Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your data have some suggestion of trend (negative). I'd suggest using [Double Exponential Smoothing](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc433.htm), as opposed to the sample mean, which could end up overpredicting your future values.

I applied double exponential smoothing to your data, and tentatively found that $\alpha=0.6,\gamma=0.1$ to be reasonably good. See below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Eupraxis, I am not familiar with the double exponential. So, my question is, this method can apply to the other data sets?

Comment: @ModnoizAntonio yes, it is a general method for generating forecast values.

Comment: @eupraxis1991 Is it working for both positive and negative trends right? If yes, then thank you for your suggestions. :)

Comment: @ModnoizAntonio yes, it will adapt to changes in trend, it only requires initial estimates of the mean value and trend for a given time series, then it updates itself after new data come in.